# How do I proof $(-1) ^ n = 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I know at the back of my head by exhaustion that this proof is true. But I just don't understand how do I proof this on paper. Here's my work so far:

$$
\begin{align*}
n &= 2a
\\(-1)^{2a} &= 1
\end{align*}
$$

I don't know how to approach this problem after that.

Comment: but what if $n=2a+1$? so this is clearly not true.

Comment: Hint: a property of exponents is $x^{ab}= (x^a)^b$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're told that $n$ is even, then the final steps are
$$
(-1)^{2a} = ((-1)^2)^a = 1^a = 1
$$
If you're not told that $n$ is even, then you can't prove that $(-1)^n = 1$, because it isn't true in general. Specifically, you're not allowed to say that $n = 2a$ aith $a$ being an integer. If you try anyways, $a$ could be a fraction, and you must be *very* careful with negative numbers raised to fractional exponents. I strongly advise you to avoid the concept completely.

Answer (score 2):

it is clear that we have $$(-1)^{2m}=1$$ and $$(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$$
since $$((-1)^2)^m=1$$ and $$(-1)^{2n+1}=(-1)^{2n}\cdot (-1)^1=-1$$

Comment: I can solve up to that, if you read my description, but I needed assistance after that.

Comment: i have edited my post

Answer (score 1):

We can write as $$(-1)^n=(-1)^{2a}=\left((-1)^2\right)^a=(1)^a=1$$